# how to find the largest value's key in a dictionary without built in functions

Tags: python

I have task to find the largest value in a dictionary key and if there are keys that are both the largest value then we go with the largest key:
so, for example: {"1":5,"6":1,"2":3,"4":5} I would want this to return 4
what I've tried so far:

```
        largest = 0 
        for i in dict:
            val = dict[i]
            if val > largest:
                largest = value
```

this find the largest value but the wrong key for dictionaries like ["2":3,"4":1,"2":3]

Comment: @Mark sorry forgot to delete

Answer (score 0):

In that iteration, the key is i.
so you can use another variable to get the right key

```
dict = {"1":5,"6":1,"2":3,"4":5}
largest = 0
key = "1"
for i in dict:
  val = dict[i]
  if val > largest:
    largest = val
    key = i
print(key) # "1"
```

And python dictionary can't get duplicated keys.
so dict like `{'2':3, '2':3}` is impossible